# How and what do responseattributes return for the Here Batch Geocoder API?

Tags: here-api

The [Here Batch Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/request-parameters.html) indicates that the `responseattributes` request parameter can be used.  I'm interested in getting geocode quality results back from a batch geocode file.

In the [Response Attribute switches documentation](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/key-concepts-attribute-switches.html) it indicates that the default options would be `On by default: matchQuality, matchType`.  But I'm not clear on how this actually gets returned from the batch geocoding API.  It sounds like these attributes would be returned in the response, and in the [API Explorer for the standard geocoder](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-free-form-address) API it does appear that these are returned in the JSON response.

But the Batch Geocoder API returns an XML response, and then ultimately a collection of files including a final data file.  In the [Batch Geocoder API explorer](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/batch_geocoding/batch-geocode-addresses), the sample XML response does not include either of those default fields.

At one point the batch geocoder demo credentials listed on the Here documentation worked, and I was able to pull back a small sample results file.  I did not see those default `responseattributes` columns on any of the downloaded files, either.

For the Batch Geocoder API, is there a way to get back information about the quality of the geocoded address, `matchQuality`, `matchType`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `responseattributes` parameter enables the additional response attributes to be includable with results, e.g. set it to: `responseattributes=all`
The `outcols` parameter attributes then define which ones you get and where.
I use the following request a lot to include scores for results analysis:

http://batch.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/jobs?action=run&app_code=[your-app-code]&app_id=[your-app-id]&gen=8&header=true&indelim=|&outdelim=|&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,navigationLatitude,navigationLongitude,mapViewTopLeftLatitude,mapViewTopLeftLongitude,mapViewBottomRightLatitude,mapViewBottomRightLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,county,state,postalCode,country,relevance,matchLevel,matchType,matchCode,mapReferenceId,responseAdditionalData,addressAdditionalData&addressattributes=all&locationattributes=all&responseattributes=all&maxresults=5&outputcombined=true&mailto=[yourname@domain.com]

Comment: Thank you! That pretty much confirms what I discovered.  I was having trouble finding specific examples in the documentation and the sample explorer isn't live for the batch geocoder.  Here doesn't appear to offer an obvious demo / trial / dev credentials for batch geocoding, either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when you define the output columns for a batch geocode request, you can also list "Address Match Information" fields which provide the information I'm looking for: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/data-output.html

These fields are entered in the requset query parameters and then showed up on the resulting output data file that was downloaded.

I'm still not sure what the `responseattributes` parameter does then on the batch geocoder, or if it's even relevant.