# How to get Timezone info, Timezone id in particular, in HERE API Batch geocoding process

Tags: here-api

I am moving from Google to Here-Api Geocoding service.I need to implement batch geocoding using HERE Batch Geocoder API. Till now I am able to get almost all of the needed info from Batch Geocoder API. However, I am not able to find a way to get TimeZone info in Batch Geocoder API response.
 For example,I was able to get Timezone object through Here Forward Geocoding API- by set query parameters 'gen=9&&locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone', but this two APIs-Geocoding and Batch Geocoder API seems to work slightly different.

I tried various combinations of query params using this generic URL:
http://batch.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/jobs?action=run&app_code=[your-app-code]&app_id=[your-app-id]&gen=8&header=true&indelim=|&outdelim=|&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,navigationLatitude,navigationLongitude,mapViewTopLeftLatitude,mapViewTopLeftLongitude,mapViewBottomRightLatitude,mapViewBottomRightLongitude,locationLabel,houseNumber,street,district,city,county,state,postalCode,country,relevance,matchLevel,matchType,matchCode,mapReferenceId,responseAdditionalData,addressAdditionalData&addressattributes=all&locationattributes=all&responseattributes=all&maxresults=5&outputcombined=true&mailto=[yourname@domain.com]
I took it from a response here:
[How and what do responseattributes return for the Here Batch Geocoder API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33392253/how-and-what-do-responseattributes-return-for-the-here-batch-geocoder-api)
However, neither in posted URL nor in HERE Api documentation I found a way to include in "outcols" information for Timezone(i need only the TimeZone Id anyway).My logic is basically that if params gen=9 and locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone are set it should work in Batch geocoding(as it works in Forward Geocoding API).
Looking at the documentation it seems to me that Timezone info is not included in batch geocoding response at all, which is a problem for me since I need Timezone Id and in this way after Batch geocoding I need to make request for each entry to set Timezone id.

In short, I need to take TimeZone info(TimeZone Id) from HERE Batch Geocoder API

Comment: I think that if somebody downvote, at least should share why. I do not see anything wrong with my question

Answer (score 0):

The BatchGeocoder Service does not support time zones only the Geocoder Service does support this right now.